# How to Rspec method for object within callback of another object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a class called User with definition. (Simplified version for understanding and keeping all code at one place)

```js
class User
  string type
  bool create_copy
end

after_save copy_cat
after_destroy destroy_copy_cat

def copy_cat
 if create_copy?
  User.create!(type: type, create_copy: false)
 end
end

def destroy_copy_cat
 if create_copy?
  User.where(type: self.type).destroy_all
 end
end

#RSPEC
#Test case 1
user = User.new(type: :admin, create_copy: true)
expect(user).to receive(copy_cat) . #Works fine
user.save!

#Test case 2
cc_user = User.where(type: :admin, create_copy: false).first
expect(user).to receive(destroy_copy_cat) #Works fine
expect(cc_user).to receive(destroy_copy_cat) #Doesn't work
user.destroy!
```

Is there a way I can detect a function call on cc_user object in rspec?

I verified that the function `destroy_copy_cat` is getting called though after using puts statement.

I tried with test double and spy and test failed.

Comment: I don't think this code works at all.

Comment: I have reduced my complex code to this for simple understanding and kept class structure, rspec and methods together. Do you know how to make rspec work in above case?